# strange behavior of echo in php

Tags: php, cj

I am working on Commission Junction api and I want to extract link url and image url from CJ so I have made this script but the out put is not that I expected eg. you can see that  echo $mat[0] is missing, so how can I solve this ?
thanks

```
Code:

$URI = 'https://linksearch.api.cj.com/v2/link-search?'.
            'website-id=1234567'.
            '&advertiser-ids=adid'.
            '&link-type=text+link'.
            '&records-per-page=1';
$context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' => 
                            array(
                                'method' => 'GET',
                                'header' => 'Authorization: 'myapiid'
                            )
                )
            );

$data = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($URI, false, $context));
foreach ($data->links[0] as $link) 
{
    // Sanitize data.
    $pd     =   $link->{'link-code-html'};
    echo var_dump($pd);
    preg_match('#<img\s+src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"#i',$pd,$mat);
    preg_match('#<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>#i',$pd,$matches);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo $matches[1];
    print_r($mat);
    echo $mat[0];
    echo '</pre>';
}

OUTPUT:
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  string '<a href="http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-1234567-42452100">Save up to 70% on Airport Parking</a><img src="http://www.tqlkg.com/image-1234567-42452100" width="1" height="1" border="0"/>' (length=181)

Array
(
    [0] => Save up to 70% on Airport Parking
    [1] => http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-1234567-42452100
    [2] => Save up to 70% on Airport Parking
)
http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-1234567-42452100Array
(
    [0] =>  http://www.tqlkg.com/image-1234567-42452100
)
```

Comment: Why echo a var_dump()? var_dump() sends to php://output anyway

Comment: I used vardump to confirm output only, I dont need it in my code

Comment: the only question i have - what made you think it's echo is responsible for all that mess

Comment: lol their is no mess here, only  echo $mat[0] is missing from output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are looking for resides in

```
$mat[1]
```

not in

```
$mat[0]
```

Try a var_dump instead of a print_f. Print_f reads easier, but var_dump sometimes gives more info.

Comment: u missed it in script coz I am already using it and their is only 1 key/value in $mat array so I cant use $mat[1]

Comment: I have just executed your script on my own server like this:  echo '<hr>';
    print_r($mat);
    echo '<hr>';
    var_dump($mat);
    echo '<hr>';
    echo "mat0 = ", $mat[0];
    echo '<hr>';
    echo "mat1 = ", $mat[1];
    echo '</pre>';  and it gave me the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are missinga single quote at Authorisation

```
$context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => array(
                        'method' => 'GET',
                        'header' => 'Authorization' : 'myapiid'
                        )
                     )
);
```

Comment: nope its not the problem bro cause I missed it here only not in original code...anyway thanks

Comment: Besides, if that was the case, not a single result would've been returned.

Comment: yes borniel is right that not the case coz i havent missed it in real code